# Arrangement of database columns in any DBMS

Tags: sql, database, performance, primary-key

We had a discussion in class about whether putting an identity key as the first column of the table affects the performance when writing your queries.

I think whether the identity key is the first or last column does not really matter since it will be used for linking one table with another. But then again I could be mistaken. I can't really find good articles that address this. What are your thoughts on this? And you have good references please do like wise.

Thanks!

Comment: 1st record or 1st column?

Comment: obviously 1st column . . . i rectified it though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### *In short...*

Depending on your DBMS, field order may actually make a difference, but that difference is likely to be too small to matter.

### *Slightly longer answer...*

Fields are stored together in rows, and rows are grouped in database pages<sup>1</sup>.

So when the DBMS loads a specific field, it also loads the row containing that field and the entire page containing that row<sup>2</sup>. **I/O, not CPU**, tends to be most important for DB performance, so once the row is in memory, field order typically doesn't matter (much).

Depending on the [physical row layout](http://sydney.edu.au/engineering/it/~info3404/lectures/02adv_RowFormats.pdf)...

- The DBMS may already know the offset of each field, in which case each field is equally fast.
- Or may need to "scan" through preceding fields, which is also quite fast but can make a small difference.

In fact, the DBMS may not even honor the order of fields in your CREATE TABLE statement - for example, it may move all fixed field to the front of the row and relegate the variable fields to the back.

But as always: if in doubt, **measure** on realistic amounts of data.

---

*<sup>1</sup> Which are some multiple of disk blocks. One database page may (and typically does) contain many rows.*

*<sup>2</sup> Unless the row cannot fit into page, in which case some of its fields can be "chained" into another page or stored "out of line" in some way. But let's not complicate things too much here.*

Answer (score 0):

In a truly *relational* DBMS there is no logical ordering of attributes in a table. In a SQL DBMS there *is* a logical ordering of columns but that doesn't necessarily match the ordering of data in physical storage. It is the structures used in physical storage that might influence performance and not the logical placement of columns in a table. So as a rule you are right, column order doesn't / shouldn't make any difference. Whether *physical* ordering makes a difference in any particular DBMS product very much depends on the physical storage details of that product.

Comment: Thanks! I however found this; [link](http://explainextended.com/2009/05/21/choosing-column-order/)